# Laravel TransformRequest not applying to own Request classes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request, laravel-5.4

**This issue was fixed in Laravel 5.4.9.**

The two new middleware classes doesn't apply to my own Requests.
The two new middleware are:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class
```

However, they don't apply their changes to my own requests. Forexample: I have this request:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CreateStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        var_dump( $this->all() ); // Content not handled by middleware

        return [
            // Rules
        ];
    }
}
```

When i use var_dump, I can see that the content isn't changed.

If i use `Illuminate\Http\Request` in my controller it works.

Is there any way to implement the changes in my own request classes?

Comment: when you use CreateStoreRequest in your method, try to dd($request->all()) and share the result , it should work correctly

Comment: Returns unhandled content. I've also debugged the functions, and they are running. If i use the the helper request('field'), it return handled content. The issue is I want to use the handled content in my own request class for validation.

Comment: trim and convert  it manually (use trim() and terany operators to convert)  i think that those middlewares works after the request

Comment: They dont. They work in Illuminate\Http\Request, but not in my own request. This is definitely not intended.

Comment: Same problem here, cant find a way to apply TrimStrings and ConvertEmptyStringsToNull to my FormRequest.

Comment: @PaulVidal, I've added my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in the Github rep.

Add the following to your request class.

```
public function all()
{
    $this->merge( $this->request->all() );

    return parent::all();
}
```

If you are checking for types in your rules, you might want to add "nullable" to the rules.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: fixed on v5.4.9 about 20 minutes ago!